# SQLite join not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL which selects some rows, I want it to also select the row ***following*** each row I selected, I cannot figure out how to write such a query...

The simple select:

```
SELECT myIndex, scr, date from history where x.state = "Move to Test"
```

My latest attempt:

```
SELECT myIndex, scr, date
from history as x cross join history as y on y.myIndex + 1 = x.myIndex
where state = "Move to Test"
```

Which gives: "ambiguous column name: myIndex"

If I were to specify the column tables like this;

```
SELECT x.myIndex, x.scr, x.date
from history as x cross join history as y on y.myIndex + 1 = x.myIndex
where x.state = "Move to Test"
```

I get nothing at all selected from the 'y' table...

Here's an example of what my output *should* look like:

```
391 200024   2006-11-27 16:03:43     Move to Test     < I am selecting this row
392 200024   2006-11-27 16:21:02     Dev              < I want to also select the *next* row, regardless of what's in it
395 200024   2006-11-29 10:58:17     Move to Test     < selected
396 200024   2006-11-29 12:10:29     Peer Review      < next
402 200024   2006-11-30 07:27:51     Move to Test     < selected
403 200024   2006-11-30 08:26:13     TQA              < next
408 200024   2007-05-03 08:35:40     Move to Test     < selected
409 200024   2007-05-03 08:52:53     Dev              < next
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `or y.state = "Move to Test"` to your last query, and change the `+` to a `-`.

Comment: That row may not _have_ "Move to Test".

Comment: I've added some info to my OP that should explain better.

Comment: This will work even if the row does not have "Move to Test," because adding that condition selects rows where the previous row is labeled "Move to Test."

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later:

```
WITH indexes AS (SELECT myIndex
                 FROM history
                 WHERE state = 'Move to Test')
SELECT myIndex,
       scr,
       date
FROM history
WHERE myIndex     IN indexes
   OR myIndex - 1 IN indexes
```

In earlier versions, you cannot use the CTE:

```
SELECT myIndex,
       scr,
       date
FROM history
WHERE myIndex     IN (SELECT myIndex FROM history WHERE state = 'Move to Test')
   OR myIndex - 1 IN (SELECT myIndex FROM history WHERE state = 'Move to Test')
```

Comment: This query does exactly what I asked for!  but...
Now I have discovered a flaw in my original logic...
I need to select the first row _following_ my row that does **NOT** have "Move to Test" as the state.
Thanks also to @apomene and Dan

Comment: The first following row with another state will be selected because its previous row *does* have state "Move to Test". Show an example input where you think it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correct you want  `myIndex` from both tables, so why not use:

```
SELECT x.myIndex,y.myIndex x.scr, x.date
from history as x cross join history as y on y.myIndex + 1 = x.myIndex
where x.state = "Move to Test"
```

Comment: I've added some info to my OP that should explain better